# Remove white color on highlight bar button

Tags: ios, objective-c

In one of my controller i have bar button image as follow (when tapped):
[image]

In my other controller it look like:

[image]

It always use same image from assets. I need my button to always be 2nd variant.

First (wrong) button declared as follow:

```
bbiRight = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:riVM.itemPictureName] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

                [RACObserve(((id<CDRRightNavItemProtocol>)self.viewModel), itemPictureName) subscribeNext:^(NSString * x) {
                    [bbiRight setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:x]];
                }];
```

Second (correct one) is:

```
 UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"m_starnotactive"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"m_staractive"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    btn.frame = (CGRect){88,11, 22,22};
    btn.rac_command = self.viewModel.cmdSaveToFavorites;
    RAC(btn, selected) = RACObserve(self.viewModel, inFavorites);

    UIBarButtonItem *bbiFav = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = bbiFav;
```

Problem is, first case is used in abstract class that used in many classes in my app, how to modify it so my bar button dont look white when selected?

Comment: Did you try to set UIButton tintColor to your color?

Comment: @АлексейАбдулин if i do that, i will set that color for all instances of table view create with that controller..

Comment: If you set tintColor for instance of UIButton it will has local effect only on that UIButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try to use `setTitleColor:forState:` with `UIControlStateHighlighted` or `UIControlStateSelected` to specify the color upon selecting the button.

If your image asset is transparent, you might also want to try to use 
`imageWithRenderingMode:` with `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` and configure the color using `tintColor` specifically to your requirements.